# streaming a response using axios, but only want specific key

Tags: axios

I'm attemping to stream an incoming response using axios.  The response is a massive JSON object with many keys but I only want a specific key.  But the value in this specific key is an array that has tens of megabytes of data.  The payload looks something like this:

```
{
  "requestTime": "20190606",
  "fuelStations": [{
    "a": "begin",
    ...
  }, {
    "a": "massive",
    ...
  }, {
    "a": "array",
    ...
  }, {
    "a": "here",
    ...
  }],
  "some-other-key": "goes here",
  ...
}
```

This is what I use for axios.  But I'm not sure how to get the `fuelStations` array from a response while it is being streamed.

```
axios.get(baseUrl, { responseType: "stream" }).then(response => {
  const stream = response.data;

  stream.on("data", chunk => {
    // ???
    // do something with just the fuelStations key, discard everything else
  };

  stream.on("end", () => console.log("all done streaming"));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using the `stream-json` package.  Code looks something like this:

```
const stream = await axios
  .get(baseUrl, { responseType: "stream" })
  .then(response => response.data);

const pipeline = stream
  .pipe(Pick.withParser({ filter: "fuel_stations" }))
  .pipe(streamArray());

pipeline.on("data", ({ value }) => console.log(value));
pipeline.on("end", () => console.log("end"));
```